# How to replicate existing OracleRDB ODBC connection in Oracle's SQL Developer application?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, odbc, oracle-sqldeveloper, rdbms

I am new to Oracle database in general, but I'm attempting to get Oracle's SQL Developer running on a workstation that has pre-configured System DSNs created for an OracleRDB database. I've confirmed the ODBC connections are working because I can use MS Access to connect and link to the tables. The "test" options within ODBC also succeed. Now I am trying to get a similar connection created using SQL Developer so I can see the column types and write queries in a more useful editor.

Here's what I have available when examining the ODBC connection properties:

[image: Existing ODBC configuration]

Now I'm trying to create a duplicate connection in SQL Developer, but I'm at a loss for why things don't work. I first tried using the default SQL Developer installation, but couldn't get things working. Then I discovered there's an OracleRDB extension available, so I installed that, but I keep getting this error when attempting to use similar values:

[image: SQL Developer connection screenshot]

As I stated, these ODBC connections were pre-configured on the workstation I'm using, so I don't know anything more than what is provided by the Oracle ODBC driver window.

Is there something obvious I'm not seeing or doing to replicate this connection in SQL Developer? Or perhaps something else I can do to debug this to learn more?

**UPDATE**

On the advice of one answer I'm trying to make the connection with JDBC, but having a hard time understanding what I'm doing wrong. Here's another screenshot with the connection parameters I have available, but with the server and database names changed:

[image: sample odbc connection]

With these values (the port came from my tnsnames.ora file), if I try to make a JDBC connection I keep getting the following error from SQL Developer:

[image: sql developer error]

One final attempt I did was to use the proper values in the Oracle RDB tab, and when I use them and click 'test' the *Testing Connection* dialog just spins and never seems to return:

[image: testing connection dialog]

So I apologize for the long post here, but I'm struggling because there's just something I am really not understanding about how this all works. I appreciate everyone who took the time to read this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle SQL Developer is a Java Application. You'll need to get the J[DBC Driver for RDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/rdb/index-090638.html).

Once you have that, in the SQL Developer preferences, find the Third Party JDBC section, and then use that to add an entry and point to the JAR for what you just installed.

Step by step instructions [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/rdb/documentation/rdbsdev-ug-73-130161.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and I'll try this out later tonight, but will this allow me to just use the existing ODBC connection within SQL Developer? I'm assuming JDBC is some sort of bridge from Java apps into the available ODBC connections?

Comment: No. The JDBC connection is a dedicated, ALL JAVA, connection from SQL Developer to your RDB database.  You'll have to look at the data source properties to ascertain the JDBC connection string properties that you'll use to connect.

Comment: Ok, for the record I'm not ignoring your answer, but it's not clear to me how to connect using just JDBC. If I try to create an rdbThin connection string, SQL Developer keeps telling me that it's not in a valid format. I'm going to update my question with some additional information to see if that helps.

Comment: if you import the jdbc driver correctly you'll get a RDB connection dialog you can use, n oneed to use the thin connection URL

Comment: in your screenshot, click from oracle to 'OracleRDB' and then fill out the connection details

Comment: I was never able to get this working, but I think your answer is right. I think the system I'm trying access doesn't have some server-side components set up properly to let SQL Developer log in. I am not able to make changes to it however, so I can't confirm. Thanks for taking the time to answer, and sorry it took so long to work through this.

Answer (score 0):

Working connection string for RDB Thin Driver:

RDB_DB_CONN_STR = "jdbc:rdbThin://node.myplace.com:1707/";

where node.myplace.com is the name of the OpenVMS node hosting the RDB Thin Driver, 1707 is the port number assigned to the RDB Thin Driver.